# is that possible to measure air pressure from my mouth in android?

Tags: android

I know there is a pressure sensor in android. But it is now what I want. The Pressure sensor doesn't measure when I whistle. I searched some documents from the developer site and couldn't find anything about wind pressure. Is there any way to know this?

Comment: Are you sure you want to measure **air pressure** and not **sound pressure**? Sound pressure is measured in dB (Decibel). Maybe that is what you are looking for.

Comment: the sound decibel is possible when I say "Ah~~~", but it is not what I want. I only want to measure when I whistle "whoo~~~~" not saying.

Comment: I think it is impossible. but check this. https://m.blog.naver.com/PostView.nhn?blogId=roboholic84&logNo=220533801112&proxyReferer=https:%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F. there is `고도/기압 센서(PRESSURE)`. but I don't think what you want.

Comment: thanks for concern. but it is not what I want. I already followed the google example about TYPE_PRESSURE. What I want is to measure the power of the wind by my mouth. Not decibel.